# Windows 10 Tablet touch screen inverted and offset

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, disk-image, touchscreen

We have bought some cheap 8" Windows 10 tablets in bulk from China. These come with an old pirated version of Windows 10 Pro.

We have imaged the tablet with a proper licensed version of Windows 10 Enterprise however we cannot get the touch screen to function correctly with a fresh install.

With the auto detected drivers the entire touch screen is offset by 50% (when you reach the middle of the screen it wraps the cursor to the otherside) also the Y Axis is inverted each moving up moves the cursor down and vice versa.

We have the original pirated windows WIM image and I have extracted the drivers from this image to the tablet and installed these. The issue is it still detects the touch screen as a "HID-Compliant touch screen" and remains inverted.

The Kionix KXCJ9 3-axis accelerometer SPB driver installs fine, however the Kionix Fusion driver (I believe this ties the accelerometer and screen together) Shows as "Code 10 This device failed to start".

The OEM Manafacturer barely speaks english and is close to useless so we can't seem to get the driver or instructions from them. All they do is send us a link to the WIM Image and tell us to use that.

Other than knowing that the accelerometer is a Kionix system we don't know what the screen is other than some generic IPC capacitive 1280x800 resolution screen.

If we use the pirated image and then change the windows product key to force it to install enterprise, will this carry over the touch screen drivers? Or will this be the same as a fresh install?

How can we fix the inverted touch screen axis? Surely there is a simple registry calibration etc.

Comment: Can you provide a source to the drivers so that someone else might be able to see if there's some configuration options that can be specified?

Comment: That is the problem. I just have the entire windows "DriverStore" folder, I don't actually know which driver it is meant to be using nor do I know what the hardware is called.

Comment: In device manager you should be able to see the driver files used by the device, which should at least be a start to see what files it uses.

Comment: It is just using the generic Windows "HID-Compliant touch screen" windows drivers

Comment: Finally got a driver back from the OEM, it is SileadTouch, will experiment first tomorrow and if there is no love I will reply back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEM finally sent us the Sileadtouch.fw files and drivers which fixed the problem. Unsure how I would have determined this without their help.